# squashfs errors and kernel offset errors on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, squashfs

Ubuntu 20.04 shows SQUASHFS and Kernel Offset errors.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a LiveUSB?

Comment: no, did a dual boot with windows

Comment: It reads like you're trying to boot *invalid live* media which exists on a *squash* file-system, thus the *squashfs* errors.. This will also occur if using a persistent *live* system which has now gone bad (the *live* system area anyway; any persistent data should be salvageable).   Any errors such as the kernel panic are to be ignored as the results on the system are *undefined* after *squashfs* errors start to occur, so further errors can be expected depending on what the system was doing (if it was still booting bad system errors can occur causing panic)

Comment: FYI:  The duplicate I tagged refers to install; but the error applies to any *live* environment, be it one you're installing from, or just using (persistence or no-persistence).